# How do you remove and hide HTML elements in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, removechild

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content-container" style="display:none">
         <div>John</div>
    </div>
    <div id="verifying">
         <div id="message">Verified</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this Javascript:

```
var body = document.body;
var signup = document.getElementById("content-container");

setTimeout(function(){
    body.removeChild('verifying');
    signup.style.display = "block";
}, 5000);
```

I am trying to remove `<div id="verifying">` and show `<div id="content-container">` after 5 seconds, but for some reason it is not working. Any idea why? I am loading the script after the page loads so that is not the problem.

Comment: why dont you hide verifying?? so something like : `document.getElementById("content-container").verifying.style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass an element reference to [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.removeChild), not a string:

```
body.removeChild(document.getElementById('verifying'));
```

You could also just hide it:

```
document.getElementById('verifying').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 4):

your removeChild needs to get an element, not a string

```
var body = document.body;
var signup = document.getElementById("content-container");

setTimeout(function(){
    body.removeChild(document.getElementById('verifying'));
    signup.style.display = "block";
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

to remove you can use (as stated) removeChild:

```
var x = document.getElementById('elementid');
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

And to hide an element:

```
var x = document.getElementById('elementid');
x.style.display="none";
```

EDIT:

oh and if you want it hidden but not taken "out of flow", use this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('elementid');
x.style.visibility="hidden";
```