# how to eliminate <li> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually,my problem is not solved completely...The thing is that i made a tree in mvc and for having expanded and collapsed tree ,i added this java script code which you can see below.
at first i add a 'handle' class to each

node and then i will add collapse expanded on it.But after applying this codes my tree is not displayed properly...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOrkG.png)

in the image u can see that 'fff' and 'ggg' must be in a same level because they are both children of 'eee' . 'ccc' seems to be the child of 'bbb' but it also must be in the same level as 'bbb'.Because both 'bbb' and 'ccc' are children of 'aaa'....

i dont know why java script code does  not work.

$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#tree ul").hide();

```
   jQuery("#tree li").prepend("<span class='handle'></span>");

    jQuery("#tree li:has(ul)")
      .children(":first-child").addClass("collapsed")
      .click(function () {
          jQuery(this).toggleClass("collapsed expanded")
            .siblings("ul").toggle();
      });
});

$(function () {
    $("ul#tree li").each(function () {
        as = $(this).children('a');
        if (!as.length) {  //
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What is the code you have and what is the expected results?

Comment: sorry..part of question disapeared...so i write it here again.I am so new in java script.I created a tree in MVC with 'ul' an 'li' tags
which look like below: there are some 'li' tags which have only 'span' and do not contain 'a' tags.how i can remove them?i just want to keep first' li 'and those which contain 'a' tags..

Comment: @sepideh That's exactly what it says in the question. The problem is you haven't posted the code that you need help fixing. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Take a look at the `:having()` selector in jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove and hide HTML elements in plain Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458619/how-do-you-remove-and-hide-html-elements-in-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses jQuery to hide anything without an a tag in it.  Requires jQuery.  I also cleaned up the broken html code.

```
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul id="tree">
  <li>
    <span class="handle"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle expanded"></span><a onclick="navigate('../CSS/logo_small.png');" href="#">hello</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="handle expanded"></span>
    <a onclick="navigate('../CSS/Alarm-Plus-icon.png');" href="#">helloworld</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  $(function(){ //wait for everything to load
    $("ul#tree li").each(function(){  //loop all the lis in the ul element with an id of 'tree'
      as = $(this).children('a');     //look for an 'a' elements that are children of this li
      if(!as.length){                 //if they have none, hide() them
        $(this).hide();               //hide
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: yes...this fixed my problem....i was looking for thisline  $(this).hide(); since 2 hours....thank u....

Comment: If I provided the correct code, please up vote the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to eliminate `<li>`, the best is the way that is most clear to you.

You can either eliminate an `<li>` tag by rewriting all elements in the `<ul>`. Or you can loop through all elements in the `<ul>` and delete the `<li>` you dont want.

Here is how to delete an element with jquery, answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391793/how-to-destroy-a-dom-element-with-jquery).

```
$target.remove();
```